# Scrollview is not working in Xcode 8 for Autoresizing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, xcode8, autoresize

i am using scrollview in in my app actually xcode 7 is working fine, i have migrate the xcode 7 to xcode 8.scrolllview is not working all controllers come in center.

Comment: Have you set any size class on storyboard in Xcode7 version.

Comment: Is it just about the ScrollView and all other ViewControllers are fine?

Comment: yes i am using autoresizing  to set the storyboard

Comment: all Viewcontroller is working fine problem is only scrollview.

Comment: its an bug of xcode 8 wait for the new stable release.
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/62313

Comment: now how can i solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar issue since I installed Xcode 8.
There's a bug with containers (UIScrollView, UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewCell, ...) and UIStackView.
Sometimes Xcode crash because infinite UIView size.

Wait for new release of GM XCode with this issue resolved and if you want to user beta version then **Xcode 8.1 Beta 3** resolves this issue. Please check this download [link](https://developer.apple.com/download/)

Source : [Xcode 8 GM seed Storyboard issue](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/62313)

Comment: if i am going  using Xcode 8.1 beta 2 any problem coming my app.

Comment: not sure because its not a GM Version its a beta version. take backup first after upgrade your project to Xcode 8.1 beta 2

Comment: in your sending link Xcode beta2 not there beta 3 is there.

Comment: OK with xcode8.1 beta 3 go ahead. check release note of this version. updated answer :)